# Sympy can't output a symbol on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy, symbols

everyone! I am pretty new on this platform and need your help in one thing. I am using sympy on jupyter notebook and I am programmig a dummy formula, root square, however the output for this symbol is not the [root symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQlEY.jpg), actually it is outputting sqrt instead.

I will give you guys an example

```
import sympy
```

`In:  sympy.sqrt(3)`

```
Out :sqrt(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior for SymPy. I can't test it for now but try adding `init_printing(use_unicode=True)` in your code before calling the `sqrt` function.

Source :
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/intro.html

Comment: Thank you Just by adding sympy.init_printing() solved the problem.